# Purpose of iconst_x

Tags: java, bytecode

Why do we have the iconst_* instructions?

Why would I ever want to use these instead of bipush?

I found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811774/different-behaviour-of-java-bytecode) when searching but it does not properly answer my question.

Comment: Bytecode is strongly typed. `bipush` pushes a byte, `iconst` pushes an int.

Comment: @aioobe Both the result of `bipush` and of `iconst` can be popped into an `int` variable, as demonstrated by the linked question.

Comment: `Why would I ever want to use these instead of bipush?`---because it's a single-byte instruction, just like the other answer says. What more justification do you need? It's a simple space optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a `bipush` instruction takes two bytes in the bytecode, and an `iconst_*` instruction takes one byte.